Rails fragment caching re-writes independent cache blocks as well
I have a index.html.erb page of users resource where I show some filters partial, users list and links to logout and delete. Filters partial is kept in different cache block, and links are kept in different cache blocks. But when I change text of logout to something else, all other cache blocks are also re-written which I saw from logs. I dont know but others are re-writing because they never changed actually. here is the code
<h1>Users</h1>

<!-- Cache the filter partial -->
<%= cache "users_filter" do %>
  <%= render partial: "users/partials/filter" %>
<% end %>

<table class="">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <div id="users">
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <%= render user %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Cache the "New user" link -->
<%= cache "new_user_link_v1" do %>
  <%= link_to "New user from here again", new_user_path %>
<% end %>

<!-- Cache the "Logout" link -->
<%= cache "logout_link_v1" do %>
  <%= link_to "Logout with updated text again", destroy_member_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete } %>
<% end %>

This is a rails 7 app. I am attaching logs output down there as well but I changed and append again on the logout text
Started GET "/users" for ::1 at 2024-12-25 16:44:46 +0500
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Member Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = ? ORDER BY "members"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering users/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Read fragment views/users/index:3da6fb2ac5628165974919223083092f/users_filter (0.1ms)
  Rendered users/partials/_filter.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 292)
Write fragment views/users/index:3da6fb2ac5628165974919223083092f/users_filter (0.1ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  ↳ app/views/users/index.html.erb:18
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 274)
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 54)
Read fragment views/users/index:3da6fb2ac5628165974919223083092f/new_user_link_v1 (0.1ms)
Write fragment views/users/index:3da6fb2ac5628165974919223083092f/new_user_link_v1 (0.1ms)
Read fragment views/users/index:3da6fb2ac5628165974919223083092f/logout_link_v1 (0.0ms)
Write fragment views/users/index:3da6fb2ac5628165974919223083092f/logout_link_v1 (0.1ms)
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 6.7ms | Allocations: 3045)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 11.6ms | Allocations: 5892)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 13.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 8026)


cache doesn't track changes within its block, it tracks changes in the whole template. template digest is part of the key: views/users/index:3da6fb2ac5628165974919223083092f. changing the template, changes the cache key. also it's pretty useless to cache such small chunks. caching <%= render user %> would be much more noticeable. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#collection-caching
